# iOS Swift Firebase Database Schema

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an app that needs to store these objects

```
User 
{
   auto-generated-id: String,
   name: String,
   schoolID: String,
   myClasses: String[]
}

School
{
   auto-generated-id: String,
   name: String,
   adress: String
}

Classes
{
  auto-generated-id: String,
  number: String,
  subject: String,
  schoolID: String
}
```

However I am not familiar with the NoSQL structure and am not sure how to store these objects for efficient queries

my app will have class subject, class number, school id available

the queries i will need

1)

```
select * 
from School s, Classes c
where c.subject = 'ABC' and c.number = '100', and c.schoolID = "1234"
```

2)

```
select c.*
from User u, Classes c, School s
where u.auto-generated-id = "1234" and u.schoolID = s.schoolID and c.schoolID = s.schoolID
```

What is the best way i can rearrange my schemas to fit the nosql methodology and still perform my queries

Also i keep getting the following warning because of my poor structure

Using an unspecified index. Your data will be downloaded and filtered on the client. Consider adding ".indexOn": "classNum" at somePath to your security rules for better performance

Comment: The .indexOn error can be safely ignored for now. That's a performance tuning error that you *will* need to address later, but for now with a tiny data set, it won't make much of a difference.

Comment: I like the question but can you very briefly update your question with what the desired output is of query 1. i.e. a use case would be helpful to understand what the final result is. i.e. a student wants the name and address of any schools that teach subject ABC.. and what does the *number* field represent?

Answer (score 0):

Try this database structure:

```
Users
 userid
   name:userx
   email: userx@gmail.com
 userid
   name:usery
   email:usery@gmail.com

Schools
   pushid
     name:school1
     address: at stackoverflow
   pushid
     name:school2
     address:ios section

Classes
   pushid
     number:1
     subject: Firebase
     schoolname: school1
   pushid
     number:2
     subject:ios development
     schoolname:school2

UserClass
  userid<---------if of userx
    randomid
      classname: Firebase
      schoolname: school1
  userid<--------------if of usery
    randomid
      classname:ios developement
      schoolname: school2
```

Check this:

https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/04/denormalizing-your-data-is-normal.html

In Firebase there is no `joins` or `where clause`.
You can only specify one path, so cant use two tables, only one top node and the go through the others nodes, example: `child("Users").child(userid)`

Comment: It would probably be super helpful to the OP and future readers if a sample query was included in the answer that solved the OP's query 1) with this structure.

Comment: It's been 4 days..the OP did not really respond or say anything.. so I do not know if he used it or it solved his problem